# How to get next n records in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have model called Property

and I get the first four records in my controller.

```
def index 
  @properties = Property.some_scope.limit(4)
end
```

Let's say that returns 8 properties, but I'm only grabbing the first four with the above action

How do I the get the next four records in the list? I played around with first and last, but how do you get next n amount?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are trying to achieve something like pagination?
you need to provide current `@page` to this view to display correct Property batch

```
PER_PAGE = 4

@properties = Property
                .order('created_at desc')
                .some_scope
                .limit(PER_PAGE)
                .offset(@page * PER_PAGE)
```

you can also use gem for this, for example:
https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate or https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for offset?

```
def index 
  @properties = Property.some_scope.offset(4).limit(4)
end
```

This will skip first 4 results and return from 5th to 8th record.